# iPhone application - perform post-install tasks or pre-populate core data

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

Is there a way to perform operations during the install phase of an iPhone application? I think this would be the most ideal time to perform tasks such as populating data stores (using core data). Or is there a more convenient way to:

1. pre-populate data
2. perform post-install tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a way, but you can do it by setting a boolean variable which is true only when the app is run for the first time and at that time you can pre populate the required data.

Comment: This would be the most viable method, most applications that I've installed on my iPhone tend to start out with an 'empty' shell, and then populate with data when you start them up for the first time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308832/iphone-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-detect-first-launch