# Calling a method only on the initial launch of an application

Tags: iphone

How do you call a method on only the initial launch of an application?  For example, if you wanted to put a tutorial UIAlertView on the very first launch but never again after that?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308832/iphone-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-detect-first-launch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy.  When your app launches, check `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` for the presence of a bool that you put in there.  If the boolean isn't there (or it's not YES), then show the alert and save the boolean back into `NSUserDefaults` as `YES`.

It's all of about 4 lines of code:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasShownInitialAlert"] == NO) {
  UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init...];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasShownInitialAlert"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSUserDefaults for this. Store a BOOL there saying if its firstlaunch, and set it in applicationDidFinishLaunching. Then then only time that is false is after fresh installs of the app.