# How to know an application is first run on a Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

On Windows, we can write values into registry to know that

but how can I know if my application is the first time it runs on a mac? I need to perform some initialization task.

Thanks

Comment: `~/Library/Application Data` perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the class `NSUserDefaults` (see [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

For example:

```
#define kAlreadyBeenLaunched @"AlreadyBeenLaunched"

    if (! [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kAlreadyBeenLaunched]) {
        // This is our very first launch

        // Setting userDefaults for next time
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kAlreadyBeenLaunched];

        // Do your first time stuff
        //<##>
    }
```

You will use the same class to save and retrieve user preferences.

This values will be saved in `~/Library/Preferences/<your_bundle_id>.plist`. This is useful to know for debugging, by looking at the file, but you should not rely on this implementation detail in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of other people that already asked this.

I guess this one is the most helpful. [iPhone: How do I detect when an app is launched for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308832/iphone-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-detect-first-launch)

Mention: It's working exactly the same way as on the iOS system.

Comment: It's working exactly the same way. In case you voted my answer down, try it out.