# NSUserDefaults registerDefaults with boolean value YES returns NO

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I've searched on google and on here, no luck so far.

To find out whether my application has been launched before, I use code similar to the code in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8669712/3576399).

The main difference is the negation of the key (`FirstLaunch` instead of `HasLaunched`) :

```
configuration = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[configuration registerDefaults:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"YES", @"FirstLaunch", nil]];
if ([configuration boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]) {
    NSLog(@"aha");
    // aha
    [configuration setBool:NO forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
    [configuration synchronize];
}
```

This never logs the important `@"aha"` message, unless I would programmatically set the `@"FirstLaunch"` key to `YES`.

Is this a bug or am I overlooking something? I'm merely asking out of curiosity since using the original key in the linked thread works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the default value to a string, but reading it as a `BOOL`.
Change the register defaults call to be similar to this:

```
[configuration registerDefaults:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@YES, @"FirstLaunch"]];
```

You should probably be setting the `FirstLaunch` value to `NO` within that if block as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't think of that.