# How to print an alert view only once in my app?

Tags: ios

I want to display a message to users if there is a new version of the app they're using, and to display this message at the app's startup, only once.

I've managed to get the app final version and the bundle's one, and comparing them to display or not an alert view to propose the new app. Now I just want to know how to never display this alert again when it has been done once.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think you need my code, I just have an alert view that I want to display or not depending if it has already been displayed before, so I'm just waiting for some advices of how to do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308832/iphone-the-quickest-and-easiest-way-to-detect-first-launch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if you need to display the `UIAlertView`, store a variable in `NSUserDefaults`. For instance, in appDidFinishLaunching you could do:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"alertShown"]) {
  // display alert...
  [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"alertShown"];
}
```

In the display alert, just have the code for the alert to pop up.

Comment: it will not work when new version is released after this one.

Answer (score 1):

save the version number in user defaults and check the version with app version, if both are same then continue otherwise show the alert and update the user default variable to latest version. First time leave the user default blank string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea of how to do it.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application … {
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {
  // display alert...
  [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];
}
// rest of initialization ...
}
```

Here, `[defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]` reads a boolean value named notFirstRun

from the config. These values are initialized to NO. So if this value is NO, we execute the if branch and display the alert.

After it's done, we use `[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"]` to change this boolean value to YES, so the if branch will never be executed again (assume the user doesn't delete the app).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![[defaults valueForKey:@"SHOW_ONLY_ONCE"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    [defaults setValue:@"1" forKey:@"SHOW_ONLY_ONCE"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```