# How to make a screen show only on initial launch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, launch-screen

I'm trying to make the intro screens for my app - namely the terms of service screen that all users have to agree to the 1st time they download and run the app. obviously, once the users agree, i dont want to show them it again every time they log on the app. what is the best way to go about doing this? I've been reading about NSUserDefaults, but am stuck pretty much after that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: How do I detect when an app is launched for the first time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308832/iphone-how-do-i-detect-when-an-app-is-launched-for-the-first-time)

Comment: the other q is in obj-c, which i dont know.

Answer (score 3):

In your AppDelegate or whichever class needs to check for first-run status:

```
Bool isFirstRun = !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("kAppPreviousLaunchKey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"kAppPreviousLaunchKey")
if isFirstRun {
    // React here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Play with this piece of code in the AppDelegate Class

```
let launchedBefore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore  {
        print("Not first launch.")
    }
    else {
        print("First launch, setting NSUserDefault.")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    }
```