# How to detect first time app launch on Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, launching-application

Is it possible to identify when an multi-platform application is loaded on it's very first time for the user with `Delphi` Firemonkey?

Comment: Save a value in a file somewhere, and upon startup, if that file/value doesn't exist, you know it's never started before.

Comment: That would definately do the job. Aren't there any 'official' paths as iOS does?

Comment: Define first. First for this user? First on the device? First for this version?

Comment: @Holmes: what does iOS do?

Comment: You will get the *official* paths from [`System.IOUtils.TPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TPath_Methods)

Comment: I guess your application probably has some configuration settings that are saved on the target device right? If that is true you can simply know that the application has not been run yet when these information's haven't been saved yet. Now where are you saving this settings depends from platform to platform. On Windows such approach is most commonly used with applications that allow each windows user to have its own settings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau http://stackoverflow.com/a/3300358/1549700

Comment: @DavidHeffernan first time for the user.

Comment: So then you know what you need to do right?

Comment: @Holmes: AFAIK, FireMonkey has no equivalent for that Objective-C code. You would have to use Delphi's Objective-C Bridge framework to call the relevant iOS APIs directly.  Otherwise, put a custom file somewhere in the app's private data storage on the device.